# Unpack parameter pack into std::initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Is there any way to use a parameter pack to create an initializer list of objects or to insert objects into a `std::vector`? The problem I am having is all examples of parameter packs I have seen use passed arguments for the compiler to be able to differentiate which function it needs to call. The thing is that I have no arguments to pass to the functions just the types.

Example:

```
// compiler cannot determine which function is correct
namespace impl
{
    template<class T, class... U>
    void get_type_impl(std::vector<MetaClass*>& types)
    {
        // rusty::get<T>(); just retrieves a MetaClass object for the specified type
        types.emplace_back(rusty::get_type<T>());
        impl::get_type_impl<U...>(types);
    }

    template <class T>
    void get_type_impl(std::vector<MetaClass*>& types)
    {
        types.emplace_back(rusty::get_type<T>());
    }
}

template <class... T>
std::vector<MetaClass*> get_types()
{
    std::vector<MetaClass*> types;
    types.reserve(sizeof...(T));
    impl::get_type_impl<T...>(types);
    return types;
}
```

Example Usage:

```
auto types = get_types<MovementComponent, GraphicsComponent>();
```

**Edit:**

The goal is to create a vector of objects that are created from the provided template types. The current problem I have is that the compiler cannot deduce which function to use. As both `get_type_impl` can have the same function signature.

**Solution:**

```
namespace impl
{
    template <class T>
    void get_type_impl(std::vector<MetaClass*>& types)
    {
        types.emplace_back(rusty::get_type<T>());
    }
    template<class T0, class T1, class... Tn>
    void get_type_impl(std::vector<MetaClass*>& types)
    {
        types.emplace_back(rusty::get_type<T0>());
        impl::get_type_impl<T1, Tn...>(types);
    }
}

template <class... T>
std::vector<MetaClass*> get_types()
{
    std::vector<MetaClass*> types;
    types.reserve(sizeof...(T));
    impl::get_type_impl<T...>(types);
    return types;
}
```

The solution is to force one of the `get_type_impl` to take at least 2 template types and the other to simply take 1. This creates enough a difference in the signatures for the compiler to determine which is the correct function.

Comment: For me it is not clear what you really want to achieve. xy-problem? I see a list of types but no parameter pack, as you have no parameters. So what you really want?

Comment: Another question; what is wrong about your sample code?  What feature does it not have that you want?

Comment: @Klaus my apologies I think I misunderstood what a parameter pack was. I updated to question in hopes to highlight what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The problem I had was not a lack of a feature but an incorrect implementation of a feature/better solution to the problem. The incorrect implementation was that the two function signatures could end up being identical causing the compiler to get confused as to which one to call.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure to understand but... it seems to me that you'r looking for something as follows (caution: code not tested):

```
template <typename ... Ts>
std::vector<MetaClass*> get_types()
 { return { rusty::get_type<Ts>()... }; }
```

Otherwise, to solve the problem with `get_types_impl()`, I suggest to delete the second function

```
template <class T>
void get_type_impl(std::vector<MetaClass*>& types)
{
    types.emplace_back(rusty::get_type<T>());
}
```

and substitute it with the following ground case

```
template <int = 0>
void get_type_impl (std::vector<MetaClass*> const &)
 { }
```

The idea behind this is add (`emplace_back()`) elements in `types` through the first version of `get_types_impl()` and make so the last call, when the variadic type list `U...` is empty and is called

```
impl::get_type_impl<>(types);
```

, is hijacked (thanks the default not type template parameter `int=0`) to the ground case.

Comment: Your initial thought is correct. Your other suggested implementation is very close to identical to what I have now. I updated my question to highlight a fix that I have done. I think the problem was that I misunderstood what a parameter pack was which caused a large portion of the confusion.

Comment: @Matthew what is wrong with the first implementation? It is much simpler and clearer.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler the first implementation above did not work when I attempted it. That was the first attempt that I had before I arrive at the implementation I have now.

Comment: @Matthew this is strange, since I managed to test and run a similar solution for `template <typename T>
const std::type_info* get_type()
{ return &typeid(T); }`
this works with C++11 support (no need for C++14):
`template <typename ... Ts>
std::vector<const std::type_info*> get_types()  { return { get_type<Ts>()... }; }
`, which is almost identical to the code in the answer. What error do you get?

Comment: @MichaelVeksler let me test this again. I did have a slightly different syntax and knew that the method I am using now would work so I probably messed something up and switched to quickly to verify I didnt do something wrong in the suggested implementation.